# Error launching browser in Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-api-client, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to authenticate an end-user in an android app written in C# (Xamarin.Android).

I decided to try and use NuGet package `Google.Apis.Oauth.v2` which seems to expose an easy to use Oauth client.

`LocalServerCodeReceiver.ReceiveCodeAsync` throws the following:

I get `System.NotSupportedException:"Failed to launch browser with https://XXX.auth.XXX.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&scope=profile%20openid%20email for authorization. See inner exception for details."`

and it has an inner exception of `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:"Cannot find the specified file"`

Code:

```
var clientSecret = new Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ClientSecrets();
clientSecret.ClientId = ...
clientSecret.ClientSecret = ...

var initializer = new Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer(
    "https://XXX.auth.XXX.amazoncognito.com/login",
    "https://XXX.auth.XXX.amazoncognito.com/login");
initializer.Scopes = new List<string> {"profile", "openid", "email"};
initializer.ClientSecrets = clientSecret;
var flow = new Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer);

var authCodeRequestURL = flow.CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest("https://www.google.com");
authCodeRequestURL.ResponseType = "token";
var uri = authCodeRequestURL.Build();

var cancellationTokenSource = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();

var codeReceiver = new Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver();
var task = codeReceiver.ReceiveCodeAsync(authCodeRequestURL, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

- Do I need to ask for a specific permission in the application manifest?
- Instead of redirecting to www.google.com, I've heard you can redirect to an app, I'm not really sure how to do that, is it http://my_app_package_name or http://my_app_title, something else?
- Is it possible not to rely on that library for launching the browser and instead get the RequestUri and start an `Activity`, if so how will the app become aware the end-user completed the SignIn process and how will the app retrieve the token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but `Google.Apis.Oauth.v2` does not support Xamarin, and there's no simple way to get it working.
Unfortunately no `Google.Apis.*` packages currently support Xamarin.

You might find the [`Xamarin.Auth`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Auth/) package does what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to redirect to an app after authentication in the browser completes.

It's called a "Deep Link" and it's documented at [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html), essentially you need to declare an IntentFilter on your Activity, which registers with the Android OS that if someone clicks or an page redirects to a specific URI, your app gets called. The token that's appended to the URI can then be read inside your app.

Comment: Can you post a working example?  Your instructions are a bit vague.